# Mallet SimpleTagger different number of predicates

Tags: java, mallet, crf

I was trying the `SimpleTagger` tutorial provided [here](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/sequences.php). I've run the exact same commands as provided on the page i.e.

`java -cp "class:lib/mallet-deps.jar" cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --train true --model-file nouncrf sample`

and

`java -cp "class:lib/mallet-deps.jar" cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --model-file nouncrf stest`.

Here are my `sample` and `stest` files.

`$ cat sample`

```
Bill CAPITALIZED noun  
slept non-noun  
here LOWERCASE STOPWORD non-noun
```

`$ cat stest`

```
CAPITAL Al  
        slept  
        here
```

However, my output is different to the one on their page. This is the output I get.

```
Number of predicates: 9  
noun   
non-noun   
non-noun
```

My questions are

> 1. What does the "number of predicates" denote?
> 2. Why do I get 9 predicates whereas, the official source claims 5 predicates for the same input files?

I'm using Mallet 2.0.8, if that matters.

Comment: I get 9 as well if that helps

Answer (score 0):

When you start training, the first message that `SimpleTagger` gives you is:

```
Number of features in training data: x
Number of predicates: y
```

The number of predicates, `y`, is the number of distinct tokens (or lines) that your training data contains.

When you label a file using the model from the previous train (that had `y` predicates), you get a message:

```
Number of predicates: z
```

This `z`, is the sum of `y` and the number of distinct tokens (or lines) that the file you want to label contains. That is why `z` is always greater (or equal) than `y`. If for example you try to label an empty of content text file with a model that had `y` predicates, you will get a number of predicates `y`, which is `y + 0 = y`, cause your empty file had `0` labels.